# Properties of $f(f(x))=g(x)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations, function-and-relation-composition

With reference to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pbce5abVNc&pp=ygUmaXJhbiBvbHltcGlhZCBxdWVzdGlvbiBmKGYoeCkpPXheMi14KzE%3D) Youtube video, I was trying to find out what important information we can gain from the equation $f(f(x))=g(x)$ [Assume all functions to be real]

One particularly interesting one that I found was this:

Consider $\text{Fix}(g)$ to be the set of all real numbers invariant under the map $g$ (which is to say that $\text{Fix}(g)=\{x:x\in\mathbb{R},g(x)=x\}$). Now,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
&&f(f(x))=g(x)\\
&\implies& f(f(f(x)))=f(g(x))\\
&\implies&g(f(x))=f(g(x))
\end{eqnarray}$$
*This implies compositional commutativity of the 2 functions.*
Now for any arbitrary $x_0$ in $\text{Fix}(g)$:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
&&g(f(x_0))=f(g(x_0))\\
&\implies& g(f(x_0))=f(x_0)
\end{eqnarray}$$
So, $f(x_0)$ must also be in $\text{Fix}(g)$, as it is invariant under $g$.

So, we can conclude that *if $x_0$ is invariant under $g$, then $f(x_0)$ will also be invariant under $g$*

Similarly, we can also show that *if $x_0$ is invariant under $f$, then $g(x_0)$ is also invariant under $f$.*

[This is particularly useful when $\text{Fix}(g)$ has only one element]

Now my question is: **What are the other useful pieces of information that we can extract from $f(f(x))=g(x)$?**

I know this is a little broad-ended, but I am looking for all possible perspectives to inspect this problem. I am intending for the answers and comments to this question to be a compendium of everything that we can extract from the relation.

Comment: Actually you can show that the set of fixed points of $f$, call it Fix$(f)$, is the same as the set of fixed points of $g$ (assuming that $f$ and $g$ have the same domain of definition), call it Fix$(g)$. Indeed, if $f(x) = x$, then $g(x) = f(f(x)) = x$ so Fix$(f) \subset$ Fix$(g)$. Now if $g(x) = x$, then $f(f(x)) = x$ but using $f(x) = g(f(x))$ and applying $f$ on both sides, we get $x = f(g(f(x))) = g(x)$. Hence Fix$(f)$ = Fix$(g)$.

Comment: @NaNoS , I agree upon your proof till $\text{Fix}(f)\subseteq\text{Fix}(g)$ (It should be just subset, not proper subset though), but, there seems to be some problem in the 2nd part... As [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kjoqdfetip) shows, if we choose $f(x)=7\sin (x)$, we have a value (approximately $1.172$) belonging to $\text{Fix}(g)$ which is not present in $\text{Fix}(f)$

Comment: Thank you for your vigilance, actually I just prove that $g(x) = x \Rightarrow g(x) = x$... (we’ll lie and say I was tired when I wrote this message). I leave my comment so that people can have a good laugh :).

Comment: @NaNoS, added your $\text{Fix}(.)$ notation in the post. It looked pretty cool. (And mistakes are a common byproduct of creative work :) )

Comment: @AugustoSantos, unfortunately, I am not informed enough to understand your points in depth, but you are considering $f$ as the step to step evolution function over a set of real numbers right?

Comment: @AugustoSantos also, though I clearly have no grasp on the topic of your comment, I believe that (iii) might not hold over all discrete input spaces. Consider the input set $\{1,0\}$ with $f$ as a function that inverts its input. While the outputs of $f$ cover every possible output, whether we start from $0$ or $1$ , $g$ will not do so. Or am I supposed to consider only continuous domains?

Answer (score 3):

I happen to have some notes about this equation. In particular, it is useful for showing that for some $g$, $f(f(x)) = g(x)$ has no solutions, by analyzing the orbits of $g$. I wrote this in order to show
$$f(f(x)) = x^2 + 3x - 3$$
has no solutions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, though the results I get are more general.

$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert #1 \rvert}$

Throughout, suppose $f(f(x)) = g(x)$, where $g$ is some given function and we want to solve for $f$.

**Proposition**: Let $x_0$ be a fixed point of $f$. Let $S_k$ be the set of $x$ such that $g^{(k)}(x) = x_0$. If $f(x_0) = x_0$ and $\abs{S_1} = 2$, then $S_2 = S_1$.

**Proof**: Let $S_1 = \{x_0, x_1\}$. Then we have
$$x_0 = f(g(x_1)) = g(f(x_1)).$$
So $f(x_1) \in \{x_0, x_1\}$. But $f(f(x_1)) = x_0$, so $f(x_1) \neq x_1$. So $f(x_1) = x_0$.

Now suppose for the sake of contradiction that $x_2 \in S_2 \backslash S_1$. Then $g(x_2) \in S_1 \backslash S_0$, so $g(x_2) = x_1$. Thus
$$g(f(x_2)) = f(g(x_2)) = f(x_1) = x_0.$$
So $f(x_2) \in S_1 = \{x_0, x_1\}$. But in either case, we have $g(x_2) = f(f(x_2)) = x_0$, contradiction!

$\square$

For example, let $g(x) = x^2 + 3x - 3$ and $x_0 = 1$. We have $S_1 = \{1, -4\}$ and $\abs{S_2} = 4$. So $x_0$ cannot be a fixed point of $f$.

**Proposition**: Let $I_k$ be the set of $x$ such that $g^{(k)}(x) = x$. Then

1. $f$ is a bijection from $I_k \backslash I_{k - 1}$ to itself.
2. It is not possible that $\abs{I_2 \backslash I_1} = 2$.

**Proof**: First, note that $f$ is injective on $I_k$, as $f^{(2k)}(x) = x$ holds.

Suppose $a \in I_k \backslash I_{k - 1}$. Note that $g^{(k)}(f(a)) = f(g^{(k)}(a)) = f(a)$, so $f(a) \in I_{k}$.

For the sake of contradiction, suppose $f(a) \in I_{k - 1}$. Then $f(a) = g^{(k - 1)}(f(a)) = f(g^{(k - 1)}(a))$. But $g^{(k - 1)}(a) \neq a$ and both lies in $I_k$, contradicting the injectivity of $f$!

So $f$ maps $I_k \backslash I_{k - 1}$ to itself. The inverse of $f$ is $f^{(2k - 1)}$.

If $\abs{I_2 \backslash I_1} = 2$, then since $f$ is a bijection on $I_2 \backslash I_1$, we have $g(x) = f(f(x)) = x$ for any $x \in I_2 \backslash I_1$, contradicting the fact that $x \notin I_1$.

$\square$

For example, let $g(x) = x^2 + 3x - 3$. We have $I_1 = \{1, -3\}$ and $I_2 = \{1, -3, \sqrt{3} - 2, -\sqrt{3}-2\}$. So a corresponding $f$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful answer! (+1) Though I am able to comprehend the logical basis of your arguments, I am unable to get a more intuitive foothold (like how someone might _discover_ this on their own). Perhaps you’d care to elaborate?

Comment: Also for those $x_0$ in $I_2$, the only possible sequences of terms that arise by applying $f$ repeatedly on $x_0$ are $\{x_0,x_0,x_0,x_0\}$, $\{x_0,x_1,x_0,x_1\}$ and $\{x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ [Tested by using cases at each step of function application]. Out of these, the first two will also get counted in $I_1$, while the third one wouldn't be. So for each occurrence of a 3rd sequence-like orbit, we would count 4 more in $I_2$ than in $I_1$. So, I think we can say that $|I_2\backslash I_1|$ will always be a multiple of $4$. Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: Yes I agree with this observation. I don't have a good intuition about these statements either...

Comment: Your concept of "orbit" was very useful. It was what led to the observation.